# How to put bibliography style acm in lower case

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I used acm style (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles)
but I want it in "normal mode" not in uppercase , it is possible to modify acm style?

> [1] EINSTEIN, A. Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Ko ̈rper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]. Annalen der Physik 322, 10 (1905), 891–921.
>
> [2] GOOSSENS, M., MITTELBACH, F., AND SAMARIN, A. The LATEX Companion.
>   Addison- Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
>
> [3] KNUTH, D. Knuth: Computers and typesetting.

I want to have like this

> [1] Einstein, A. Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Ko ̈rper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]. Annalen der Physik 322, 10 (1905), 891–921.
>
> [2] Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., and Samarin, A. The LATEX Companion.
>   Addison- Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
>
> [3] Knuth, D. Knuth: Computers and typesetting.

Comment: It's not uppercase, but small caps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not uppercase, but caps and small caps.

Since the style uses `\sc` (deprecated since 1995), it's quite easy to get rid of it:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2015,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\renewcommand{\sc}{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained. Use your own bib file in the argument to `\bibliography`.

[image]